# Bottom navbar rounded corners

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to give some rounded corners to my bottom navbar. For that, I have to make the background of its container transparent but I don't know how.

This is what I did int the `Scaffold`:

```java
bottomNavigationBar: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0), topRight: Radius.circular(30.0), ),
        child:BottomNavigationBar(
          //elevation: 0.0,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white10,
```

and the result :

[image]

There is still by default a white background. I tried to wrap my `ClipRRect` in a container with a transparent background but it did not work.

Any idea ?

Comment: Did u find any solution to this? I have the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not

Answer (score 62):

need a little bit shadow like

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(                                             
  decoration: BoxDecoration(                                                   
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(                                           
      topRight: Radius.circular(30), topLeft: Radius.circular(30)),            
    boxShadow: [                                                               
      BoxShadow(color: Colors.black38, spreadRadius: 0, blurRadius: 10),       
    ],                                                                         
  ),                                                                           
  child: ClipRRect(                                                            
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(                                           
    topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),                                            
    topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),                                           
    ),                                                                         
    child: BottomNavigationBar(                                                
      items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[                                        
        BottomNavigationBarItem(                                               
          icon: Icon(Icons.favorite), title: Text('Favourite')),               
        BottomNavigationBarItem(                                               
          icon: Icon(Icons.favorite), title: Text('Favourite'))                
      ],                                                                       
    ),                                                                         
  )                                                                            
)
```

without shadow :

[image]

with shadow :

[image]

Comment: I tried with the shadows :  https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/421445316617961502/607278637741375531/unknown.png It is a bit better, but we still se the white background. It works well with yours because the background of your app is white. That's not the case for me :/

Comment: I mean as you see in the picture, my app background is kinda grey

Comment: What I mean is that in the exemple you shewed me, it works because your background is white. Mine is grey, so we still see a distinction between my app background and the white background generated by the BottomNavigationBar

Comment: it does not work for iOS apps

Answer (score 30):

Inside Scaffold, set [extendBody](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/extendBody.html) property to true. This lets body extends to the bottom of the Scaffold, instead of only extending to the top of the bottomNavigationBar.
This should fix your problem.

Example:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: bodyOfApp(),
      extendBody: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(),
    );
   }
```

Comment: This works but you'll need to be careful about stuff at the bottom of your body and compensate for the extended canvas

Answer (score 6):

All the above answers use ClipRRect in some way which is very costly computation-wise. Thus, as an alternative use Material Widget, here's how:

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(30), topLeft: Radius.circular(30)),
      ),
      child: Material(
        elevation: 0.0,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.favorite), title: Text('Favourite')),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.favorite), title: Text('Favourite'))
          ],
        ),
      )),
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the `canvasColor` in your `Theme` to transparent.

```
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    canvasColor: Colors.transparent
  ),
);
```

Comment: waw, this is very helpful. Just setting the canvasColor to transparent saved me alot of unnecessary codes. thanks @Faatman

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
class _DashBoardActivityState extends State<DashBoardActivity> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
  TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("BottomNavigationBar"),
      backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,),
      body: Container(child: Center(child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),),),
      bottomNavigationBar: CreateBottombar(context),
    );
  }


  final _widgetOptions = [
    new ListFragScreen(),
    new ConsultationFragScreen(),
    new LabFragScreen(),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  Container CreateBottombar(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      //add ClipRRect widget for Round Corner
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
          topRight: Radius.circular(24),
          topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
        ),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          //add background color
          backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.business),
              label: 'Business',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.school),
              label: 'School',
            ),
          ],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62499585/7053030) suggested by @CoderMonk should work. If it doesn't then I think you might be using something like `SafeArea()` widget in the body of your `Scaffold()`, If so you should either remove it completely or do something like

```
Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    bottom: false,
    child: ...
  ),
);
```

Comment: Use with 
extendBody: true,

Answer (score 1):

The solution with extendBody that helps to remove the background of the bar:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true, // Important: to remove background of bottom navigation (making the bar transparent doesn't help)
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(12.0), // adjust to your liking
              topRight: Radius.circular(12.0), // adjust to your liking
            ),
            color: your_bar_color, // put the color here
          ),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(backgroundColor: Colors.transparent), // don't forget to put it
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // widget
            // widget
            const SizedBox(height: kBottomNavigationBarHeight) // add space at the bottom due to extendBody property for proper scrolling
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```